# Is it possible / best practice to add different kafka brokers to the same cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

In case I have a cluster and I have in it a broker consume/produce event x from microservice MS-1
Can I add additional broker to the same cluster so it will consume/produce event y from microservice MS-2 or for each broker type have to generate dedicated cluster ?

Is it best practice or even possible ?

I am asking since I have seen that brokers used as leader-follower on the same cluster, means all are replicas of the leader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brokers are the nodes in the cluster that handle requests from your clients. Your clients are Consumers or Producers (or both) that interact with your cluster (Consumers and Producers are not Brokers).

While you can add brokers to a running cluster, the concept I think you're looking for is a Topic, which is a group of related event/message types. Your cluster can support many Topics, and yes, microservice1 could produce events to Topic1, and microservice2 could produce events to Topic2.

Comment: Thanks mate! 
Is a broker can contain different types of topics ?
"Topic, which is a group of related event/message types." How a group defined ?

Comment: Physically, by running 'kafka-topics.sh --create --topic topicname' or do you mean what defines a group of related messages? This would be by whatever makes sense functionally for your system. You could use a 'customer' topic for customer related events, or you could define separate topics for different kinds of customer events, eg. CustomerAccountCreatedTopic, CustomerAccountUpdatedTopic, CustomerAccountClosedTopic. Whatever makes sense for your functionality.